# Insert Trigger Working, Update Trigger Not Working. What is wrong with my APEX?

Tags: apex, trigger, field-update

I have a trigger that is counting the number of 'Open' tasks on an Account object.

The trigger is working correctly when I add a new Task to an account, however when I 'close' the task the update is not working correctly.

E.g. When I add a new task to my account it increments `Number_of_Open_Tasks__c` by 1 which is what should happen, and when I close a task `Number_of_Open_Tasks__c` stays at 1 for the account when it really should be 0.

The odd thing is in my logs I can see that the value has change and is being set in the `update` method, but the value is not actually updating.

I'm at a loss here.

Any suggestions are appreciated

```
trigger UpdateAccountOpenTasksTrigger on Task (after delete, after insert, after undelete, after update) {

    public List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
    public id accountId;
    public integer openNumber = 0;

    if (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUnDelete || Trigger.isUpdate) {

        for (Task t : Trigger.New) {
            accountId = t.WhatId;
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'Account Id: ' + accountId);

        }

        taskList = [SELECT id, Status FROM Task WHERE WhatId = :accountId];
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'TaskList size: ' + taskList.size());

        for (task t : taskList) {
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'Current Task: ' + t);
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'Current Task Status: ' + t.Status);
            if (!t.Status.equals('Closed')) {
                System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'Updating Open Task Number');
                openNumber = openNumber + 1;
            }
        }

        List<Account> accountListToUpdate = new List<Account>();

        List<Account> accountListToCheck = [SELECT id, Number_of_Open_Tasks__c FROM Account WHERE id = :accountId];

        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'Number of accounts to check: ' + accountListToCheck.size());

        for (Account a : accountListToCheck) {
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'Checking Account: ' + a);
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'Current Open Task Number: ' + openNumber);
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'Current Number of Open Tasks: ' + a.Number_of_Open_Tasks__c);
            a.Number_of_Open_Tasks__c = openNumber;
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'Changed Number of Open Tasks: ' + a.Number_of_Open_Tasks__c);
            accountListToUpdate.add(a);
        }

        if (accountListToUpdate.size() > 0) {
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'Updating Accounts ... ');
            update accountListToUpdate;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the logs showing the value is being (should be?) updated:

```
15:57:29.1 (794198586)|USER_DEBUG|[48]|INFO|Current Number of Open Tasks: 1
15:57:29.1 (794284374)|USER_DEBUG|[50]|INFO|Changed Number of Open Tasks: 0
15:57:29.1 (794310584)|USER_DEBUG|[55]|INFO|Updating Accounts ...
15:57:29.1 (794353764)|DML_BEGIN|[56]|Op:Update|Type:Account|Rows:1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause was in this line of your code:

```
if (!t.Status.equals('Closed')) {...}
```

Upon going through Task's Status field, could see that the actual value is **Completed** and that this value determines a **Closed** Task. So if you change the value from **Closed** to **Completed**, you will get the results as desired.

Got this working by copying your code and changing the value to **Completed** and it worked fine.

```
if (!t.Status.equals('Completed')) {...}
```

Also below is a screenshot of how the Status fields belong to a particular Category for Task.

[image]